# R making levels with no value/empty to make lealfet legend/map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

So I´m making a shiny app that displays a leaflet map, which is intended to visualize data from a survey. One of the things I want to visualize is a value that ranges from 0 to 14 that shows which of two statements you agree the most with(0 means you agree wholly with statement A, 14 that you agree wholly with statement B and 7 means you agree with both equally).

Currently I have a legend that looks like this

[image]

The problem is that the data is dynamic and it´s possible that there is no value higher then 9 for example. When that happens I get the warning...

```
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: invalid 'labels'; length 3 should be 1 or 2
```

And the application crashes. My code for getting the levels to use in the legend/map looks like this...

```
faktorTest <- factor((områden[,2] >= 5) + (områden[, 2] >= 9), 
              labels = c("Less than 5", "Between 5 and 9", "More than 9"))

        colorTest <- colorFactor(c("darkred","darkorange","darkgreen"),
                                    levels = faktorTest,ordered=FALSE)
leafletProxy("map")%>%
        clearShapes()%>%
        clearControls()%>%
        addPolygons(data=uv84, weight = 2, fillOpacity = 0.8, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                    popup = pop_up, color = ~colorTest(faktorTest))%>%
        addLegend("bottomleft", pal = colorTest, values = faktorTest, na.label ="Ingen data", title =input$var2 )
```

Is there a way to create all three levels even though the values aren´t represented? Say you have no value under 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `cut` to generate the factors:

```
cut(områden[,2],breaks=c(-Inf,5,9,+Inf),include.lowest=T,labels = c("Less than 5", "Between 5 and 9", "More than 9"))
```

It creates 3 `levels` even if one of them has no data point.